# How to inser variable in .replace for fs in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

How  will I gonna pass the ref variable inside the replace()? I try it my code below, b

```
var ref = "www.facebook.com";

fs.readFile('text.html','utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    var result = data.replace(/href="'+ref+'"/g, 'href="changeRef"');

    fs.writeFile('text.html', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        next();
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RegExp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_constructor.asp) class instead of inline regex.

`data.replace(new RegExp('href="'+ref+'"', 'g'), ...)`

But I recommend you to use [streams](https://community.risingstack.com/the-definitive-guide-to-object-streams-in-node-js/?utm_source=nodeweekly&utm_medium=email) to do the job instead of callbacks. It would be something like this:

```
const through2 = require('through2');
const fs = require('fs');
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('destPath');

fs
  .createReadStream('path')
  .pipe(new through2((data, enc, cb) => {
      const chunk = data.toString();
      chunk = chunk.replace(new RegExp('foo', 'g'), 'bar');
      cb(null, chunk);
   }))
   .pipe(writable);
```

Comment: Thanks men. I'll this later